# What should I do? Doctrine relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create a dynamic form Photo with these fields:

- title
- album

Album is a checkboxes field ( with 'multiple' attr ).

Photo has a manyToOne relationship with Album.

What I want to do is persist several times the photo with different album values, not persist an arrayCollection of albums in one photo.

I tried to do

> if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
>
> ```
>     $form->bind($request);
>
>         if ($form->isValid()) { 
>                 $data = $form->getData();
>                 $listeAlbum = $data['album'];
>
>                 foreach ($listeAlbum as $album) {
>      
>                   $em->persist($photo);
>                   $em->flush();
>                 }
> ```

I get the error ( at the line bind->($request) )

```
  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MySite\TestBundle\Entity
    \Photo::setAlbum() must be an instance of MySite\TestBundle\Entity\Album,
    instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, ...
```

Is there a way to do this?

---

EDIT : more code.

my form type

> > class PhotoType extends AbstractType {
>
> ```
> private $securityContext;
>
> public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
> {
>     $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
> }
>
> public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
> {
>     $builder->add('file', 'file')       //  , array("attr" => array("multiple" => "multiple",  ))
>             ->add('titre');
>             
>     $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
>     if (!$user) {
>         throw new \LogicException(
>             'The FriendMessageFormType cannot be used without an authenticated user!'
>         );
>     }
>
>     $builder->addEventListener(
>         FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
>         function (FormEvent $event) use ($user) {
>             $form = $event->getForm();
>
>             $formOptions = array(
>                 'multiple' => true, //several choices
>                 'expanded' => true, // activate checkbox instead of list
>                 'class' => 'EVeilleur\DefuntBundle\Entity\Album',
>                 'property' => 'titre',
>                 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
>                     // build a custom query
>                     return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->add('select', 'u')
>                                                        ->add('from', 'EVeilleurDefuntBundle:Album u');
>                                                      //  ->add('where', 'u.id = ?1')
>                                                      //  ->add('orderBy', 'u.name ASC');
>
>                 },
>             );
>
>             // create the field, = $builder->add()
>             // field name, field type, data, options
>             $form->add('album', 'entity', $formOptions);
>         }
>     );
>
>
> }
>
> /**
>  * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
>  */
> public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
> {
>     $resolver->setDefaults(array(
>         'data_class' => 'EVeilleur\DefuntBundle\Entity\Photo'
>     ));
> }
>
> /**
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function getName()
> {
>     return 'eveilleur_defuntbundle_photo';
> } }
> ```

entity relation, in Photo.php

> ```
> /**
>  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EVeilleur\DefuntBundle\Entity\Album")
>  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
> */
> private $album;
> ```

Comment: Are you sure getting error on that line? Otherwise I think you need to create new object of album and set $photo->setAlbum($newAlbumObj); then persist it. Your code is insufficient to give proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer; i get an error when i comment all but that line so i guess it comes from there ? What do you mean by creating a new object ? I 've added some additional code, if it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding Album to your Photo form as a single entity field, but your options mean it gets translated into a set of checkboxes that is logically turned on submit by Symfony into an ArrayList.  Your Photo entity expects only a single Album.

Could you post the rest of your Photo entity, specifically the setAlbum method (apologies if you don't actually need to create one in this case, I always create mine even if they're trivial!)?

If Photo is ManyToOne with Album, then many Photos can be in one Album, and the Album field should probably be a dropdown - you shouldn't be able to choose multiple Albums.  This may be the root of the issue.

If many Photos can be in one Album, but also each Photo can be in many Albums, then you really have a ManyToMany relationship, doesn't seem to be modelled like that here.